# Need a queue that can support multiple readers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I need a queue that can be processed by multiple readers.

The readers will dequeue an element and send it to a REST service.

What's important to note are:

- Each reader should be dequeueing different elements. If the queue has elements A, B & C, Thread 1 should dequeue A and Thread 2 should dequeue B in concurrent fashion. And so forth until there's nothing in the queue.
- I understand that it is CPU intensive to always run in busy loop, peeking into the queue for items. So I am not sure if a Blocking queue is a good option.

What are my options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) are two options that immediately come to mind, depending on whether you want blocking behavior or not.

As Adamski notes, the `take()` method of the `LinkedBlockingQueue` does not needlessly burn cpu cycles while waiting for data to arrive.

Comment: Actually I'm a little unclear as to which Queue implementation is more appropriate: LinkedBlockingQueue or ConcurrentLinkedQueue - I always use LinkedBlockingQueue out of habit.  Anyone got any recommendations here?

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not have any blocking, so is most likely not appropriate for your use case.  the standard producer/consumer collection is a BlockingQueue.  LinkedBlockingQueue is a good default choice.

Comment: Agreed with james - LinkedBlockingQueue using `take()` is probably the appropriate solution for this case.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure from your question description whether the threads need to dequeue elements in a strict round-robin fashion.  Assuming this isn't a restriction you can use `BlockingQueue`'s `take()` method, which will cause the thread to block until data is available (therefore **not consuming CPU** cycles).

Also note that `take()` implementations are atomic (e.g. [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)): If multiple threads are blocked on `take()` and a single element is enqueued then **only one** thread's take() call will return; the other will remain blocked.

Comment: No there's no need for the round-robin fashion. I might even bump up the reader thread count to 3 or 4. Sounds like LinkedBlockingQueue is a good fit for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between ConcurrentLinkedQueue and LinkedBLockingQueue is its throughput.  Under moderate thread contention ConcurrentLinkedQueue greatly out performs all other BlockingQueues.  Under heavy contetion, however, a BlockingQueue is a slightly better choice as it will appropriately put contending threads into the waiting thread set.